# How to efficiently filter Azure (kusto) container logs

Tags: azure-data-explorer

My query below seem to be in-efficient, but the Azure "ContainerLog" table contains no Container details, I do a lookup from "KubePodInventory".

```
let _podInventory = ( KubePodInventory 
       | where Namespace has "My-k8s-Namespace" 
       | where ContainerName has_any ('My-Pod' )
       | distinct ContainerID , ContainerName, Namespace, Name
                    );
ContainerLog
| where TimeGenerated between( datetime("2020-06-18 02:00:00 ") .. now())
| join kind=inner _podInventory on $left.ContainerID == $right.ContainerID
| project LogEntry, Name1, Namespace , ContainerName, TimeGenerated
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [lookup operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/lookupoperator), it should be more efficient because the join will be automatically broadcast (distributed).

Comment: I get error "BroadcastJoinBuildEvaluatorUtils: Partial query evaluator failed with message 'Stream was too long.'
probably due to the size of the KubePodInventory

Answer (score 2):

This worked well for me, combining filterd KubePodInventory with @Avnera's lookup operator seem to be fast.

```
//# Pieter2020-06 Search for log in Namespace and Container name
let _podInventory = ( KubePodInventory 
       | where Namespace has "mynamesspace-uat" 
       | where ContainerName has_any ('pod1' , 'web2' , 'pod3')
       | distinct ContainerID, ContainerName, Namespace, PodRestartCount , Name );
ContainerLog
//| where TimeGenerated between( datetime("2020-06-16 02:00:00 ") .. now())
| where TimeGenerated between( datetime("2020-07-13 19:00:00 ") .. datetime("2020-07-15 9:00:00 ") )
| where ( LogEntry has_any( "WARN", "ERRO"  ) )
| lookup kind=leftouter (_podInventory) on ContainerID
| project TimeGenerated, Name1, LogEntry, Namespace
```

Comment: how to get logs for all pods at the same time